# WPF: Lightweight nonblocking window with animation over a parent UI

Tags: wpf

I have an app in WPF which runs another exe and displays its output on a textbox. While this is running, i wanted to bring up a lightweight window over this which has just a close button. This lightweight window should look similar to lightbox in javascript, for displaying pictures or videos. The main UI behind this lightweight window should keep running with a reduced opacity.

Thanks for any help that will help me in implementing this.